# Creating new user with random password in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication, django-users

I have been working on a project where admin registers users to use the website. say in my case admin registers teachers and students of the school. I need some way to create random password for every new user and a email will be sent using registered email with the password. I am using custom user model.

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have email Id")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an username")


        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),
                          username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(email),
                                username=username,
                                password=password)
        user.role = 'ADM'
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", unique=True)
    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        ('STD', 'STUDENT'),
        ('THR', 'TEACHER'),
        ('ADM', 'ADMIN')
    ]
    role = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='STD')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = MyAccountManager()
```

here my register view.

```
@login_required
def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10,
                                                         allowed_chars='abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789')
            form.save()
            user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            send_mail(
                'Login details',
                'Here is your login details \n username : ' + username + '\n password : ' + password,
                from_email=None,
                recipient_list=[email],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            messages.success(message="Email has been sent to " + email + ".")
            return redirect('register')
    else:

        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

here is my UserRegisterForm

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['password1']
        del self.fields['password2']

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'role']
```

What are the possible ways I can set this. I tried by overriding form.save() by didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Form [`.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) accepts an optional `commit` keyword argument, if you call save() with `commit=False`, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. You can modify the data and then save it.

```
def register(request):
    ...
    f = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        u = f.save(commit=False)
        raw_password = User.objects.make_random_password(...)
        u.set_password(raw_password)
        u.save()
    ...
```

**Template**

```
<form action="..." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="password" name="password1" value="random_value" hidden>
    <input type="password" name="password2" value="random_value" hidden>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the above way. It says keyerror. reason being in the UserRegisterForm method I have deleted the password fields as I dont want them to be shown during registration. But the save method looks for field password1 and password2

Comment: @swasthiknayak the easiest way I could think of is using `hidden input`, adding two additional `input` fields in your form rendering, then it will succesfully pass the form validation phase

Comment: But the {{form}} will iteself create the password fields and will be tried to access.

Comment: `make_random_password()` is deprecated. Instead you could use `secrets.token_hex()`

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a slightly more elegant solution, especially since I didn't get where the `register` view is supposed to be.

First, in `forms.py` have this:

```py
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Password should be autogenerated
        self.fields['password1'].required = False
        self.fields['password2'].required = False
```

Then, in `admin.py` there are 2 options:

1. If there is no custom `UserAdmin` class, you can do as suggested in the previous answer and modify the template:

```html
<form action="..." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="password" name="password1" value="random_value" hidden>
    <input type="password" name="password2" value="random_value" hidden>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

2. The other option is to add a custom `UserAdmin` class to `admin.py` with a `add_fieldsets` variable or `get_fieldsets()` method that specifically exclude `password1` and `password2` fields. Here's a quick example:

```py
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(auth_admin.UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = (
                (
                    None,
                    {
                        "classes": ("wide",),
                        "fields": ("username", "is_staff", "email"),
                    },  # Note that "password1" and "password2" fields are absent
                ),
            )
```

And finally, in the `User` model, add an unusable password so that account cannot be used until password is reset or otherwise changed:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        # Set a random password for new users
        if not self.pk:
            self.set_unusable_password()
```